# Compile errors in a method

Tags: java

Why do I keep getting compile errors in this method?

```
public static boolean reverseSearch(int search, int iarr){
    for(int i=iarr.length-1; i>=0; i--){
        if(iarr[i] == search){
          return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
}
```

Comment: What's the error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the name, and the fact that you're trying to get the length your second method parameter should be an `int []`. This

```
public static boolean reverseSearch(int search, int iarr){
```

should be

```
public static boolean reverseSearch(int search, int[] iarr){
```

Answer (score 1):

seems you are trying to read and check something from an array. so you have to pass an array not an integer.so it should be **int [ ] iarr**

public static boolean reverseSearch(int search, **int [ ] iarr**)